# Configure Application Insights with Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to configure Application Insights for my webjob(Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs (v:2.3)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
{
    // Wire up with default filters; Filtering will be explained later.
    config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                .AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null)
                .AddConsole();

    config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;
}
```

The loggerFactory isn't available.

I have installed these below package.

```
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging" version="3.0.6" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have install the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

Have a look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration#webjobs-version-2x).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is the JobHostConfiguration missing
`var config = new JobHostConfiguration();`

Otherwise you can do the configuration like in following snippet

```
var builder = new HostBuilder().ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
{
    b.AddConsole();

    // If the key exists in settings, use it to enable Application Insights.
    var instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
    {
        b.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
    }
})
```